# Pass values from child component (form) into parent component (where submit button located)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have split big component into two, where currently one is child and another is parent. However currently after clicking Submit button on parent component values are somehow getting null and no data is passed into database. Why so and how to fix that?

In Record.razor.cs

```
[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
```

Record.razor:

```
  <Form Model="this" LabelColSpan="8" WrapperColSpan="16">
    <FormItem Label="Record title" NoStyle>
      <Input @bind-Value="@this.Title" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem Label="Description" NoStyle>
      <Input @bind-Value="@this.Description" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem Label="Date" NoStyle>
      <DatePicker @bind-Value="@this.SelectedDate" ShowTime="@true" OnChange="this.OnDateSelected" />
    </FormItem>
  </Form>
```

Index.razor.cs:

```
private DiaryRecord DiaryRecordModel { get; set; }
private bool isDialogVisible;
private DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

public Index()
{
  this.DiaryRecordModel = new DiaryRecord();
  this.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Index.razor:

```
  <Form Model="this.DiaryRecordModel"
        OnFinish="(e) => this.OnCreateNewDiaryRecord()">
    <FormItem>
      <Record Description="@context.Description"
              SelectedDate="this.SelectedDate"
              Title="@context.Title" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem WrapperColOffset="8" WrapperColSpan="16">
      <Button Type="@ButtonType.Primary" HtmlType="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
      <Button OnClick="(e)=>{this.isDialogVisible = false;}">Cancel</Button>
    </FormItem>
  </Form>
```

DiaryRecord.cs

```
  public class DiaryRecord
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

For example todays date is always passed into model, instead of actually selected date (other values are not taken into model):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - don't use form inside a form. Use just the one on Index.razor.

Second:
Once you do this: `Description="@context.Description"` your context looses the connection to whatever is happening with the string.

You have two options here.

1] Use [two-way binding](https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/), which will result in `@bind-Description="@context.Description"`, you also need to create `EventCaller` for every property inside `Record` component.

2] (better one) Send your whole model to `Record` component:

```cs
[Parameter] DiaryRecord DiaryRecord {get;set;}
```

```
<Input @bind-Value="@DiaryRecord.Title" />
```

```
<Record DiaryRecord=this.DiaryRecordModel/>
```

Comment: Do you say that it is better to have a long code in one component instead of splitting it into several components? BTW Thank for solution, it works!

Comment: No, quite the opposite. Separating form into multiple component is correct, but have multiple form inside each other is not.. Or how did you imply I think a long code is better?

Comment: I was just thinking if splitting is not the right way. I am quite new to blazor. Ok, so I just basically remove child Form and leave FormItems there. Have pushed an update to my repo

Comment: Will continue in repo issues!